# Changing SelectedItem value in setter has no effect on ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` whose `SelectedItem` and `ItemsSource` are data-bound to a view model. Whenever `"Blue"` is selected, the setter instead sets the value `"Green"` and fires a `PropertyChanged` event.

I'd expect the `ComboBox` to display `"Green"` in that case, instead the displayed value remains `"Blue"`.

I've tried the same with a `CheckBox` (bind to `IsChecked`, revert the value to `false` whenever it's set to `true` and fire `PropertyChanged`), and it works as expected there.

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="80" Width="100">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTestApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ComboBox.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>
        {
            "Green", "Red", "Blue"
        };

        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                selectedItem = value;

                if (selectedItem == "Blue")
                    selectedItem = "Green";

                SelectedItemChanged();
            }
        }

        private string selectedItem = "Red";

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void SelectedItemChanged() =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItem)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if Combobox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property is set to "True".

Comment: Ugh. Years later and still a headbreaker this one :) Both answers work, but the one with the Delay looks worse because one can see the delay kicking in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is indeed a bit strange. It turns out that, even though the combobox displays "Blue", its `SelectedItem` now claims to be the expected "Green". I don't know why there is a discrepancy between the displayed value and the programmatically accessible `SelectedItem` value, but I did find a workaround:

```
<ComboBox
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    x:Name="ComboBox"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Delay=1}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" />
```

The `Delay` does the trick, so there's some definitely some timing issue here.

I tried to create a proper dependency property, in the hopes that value coercion would do the trick:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItem",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MainWindow),
            new PropertyMetadata("Red", SelectedItemChanged, SelectedItemCoerceValue));

    private static void SelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private static object SelectedItemCoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
        if ("Blue".Equals(basevalue))
        {
            return "Green";
        }

        return basevalue;
    }

    public List<string> Values { get; set; } = new List<string>
        {
            "Green", "Red", "Blue",
        };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComboBox.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that one also needs the `Delay` property set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LostFocus as UpdateSourceTrigger

```
<ComboBox
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    x:Name="ComboBox"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" />
```

Comment: Hm, this seems like a workaround as well (just like the accepted answer).